# How to update mysql with regex?

Tags: mysql, regex

How to use regex update mysql

```
id | name 
1  | sac_odb
2  | iker_odb
3  | pear_odb
```

to

```
id | name 
1  | sac_oca
2  | iker_oca
3  | pear_oca
```

all the `_odb` to `_oca`, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update client_table set name = replace(name, ‘odb’, ‘oca’)
```